# Elementary OS 7 Horus - LUKS Volumes support (disk encryption)

Tags: encryption, horus, disk

I am struggling with setting up LUKS Volumes with encryption for Elementary OS 7 Horus.

I am using this tutorial: https://www.mikekasberg.com/blog/2020/04/08/dual-boot-ubuntu-and-windows-with-encryption.html

Unfortunately Elementary OS installer does not support LUKS volumes.  I cannot use any of LUKS volumes/partition I have created.

[image]

So the question is: How Can I install Elementary os with the LUKS volumes? Or in other words: How I can set up Disk encryption on Elementary OS (installed along with dual boot with Windows 10)?